# a TypeError in fit function when using keras with theano backend

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, theano

my theano version is **1.0.1+unknown**.
my keras version is **2.1.3**

i'm implementing stacked LSTM autoencoder in keras and this is my code:

```
timesteps = x_train.shape[1]
input_dim = 1
inputs = Input(batch_shape=(1,timesteps, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(7,return_sequences = True)(inputs)
encoded = LSTM(5,return_sequences = True)(encoded)
encoded = LSTM(3)(encoded)
decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(5,return_sequences = True)(decoded)
decoded = LSTM(7,return_sequences = True)(decoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim,return_sequences = True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)

encoder = Model(inputs,encoded)

sequence_autoencoder.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
optimizer='Adam')

sequence_autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
epochs=100,
batch_size=1,
shuffle=True,
)
```

It gives me the following error:

> TypeError: The broadcast pattern of the output of scan
>   (TensorType(float32, 3D)) is inconsistent with the one provided in
>   output_info (TensorType(float32, col)). The output on axis 1 is False,
>   but it is True on axis 2 in output_info. This can happen if one of the
>   dimension is fixed to 1 in the input, while it is still variable in
>   the output, or vice-verca. You have to make them consistent, e.g.
>   using theano.tensor.{patternbroadcast,unbroadcast,addbroadcast}.

Comment: What is your single data point shape?

Comment: my single training point shape is (2,1), two timesteps and one element in each timestep